# Issue with same package names in android

Tags: java, android, linked-list, resources, classpath

### Description

---

I have two android application and here are the packages in which they are located.

- `com.android.app.sample1`
- `com.android.app.sample2`

as you know every application have it's own res folder and if I want to get some string for sample1 I must write `com.android.app/sample1.R.string.some_string` and if for sample2 `com.android.app/sample2.R.string.some_string` Now if I have some other project with package

- `com.android.app.testingsamples`

and my `sample1\src` and `sample2\src` are linked as a resources to the ***testingsamples***, but when I link `src` to the ***testingsamples*** an errors like "***cant find resource R***" appears.

### What I try to solve this issue

---

I try to change my all applications package to the same `com.android.app` in that case when I link applications as a resource to ***testingsamples*** everything is okay as `R` is same and located for all in `com.android.app.R` but this is not an issue as when I try to install ***sample1*** and ***sample2*** separately the install one above one as they have same package name.

### Question

---

Is there any Idea how I can do that for all projects R will be located in the same place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and my sample1\src and sample2\src are linked as a resources to the
>   testingsamples, but when I link src to the testingsamples an errors
>   like "cant find resource R" appears.

it's because the java file that is generated for R is in sampleX\bin.
You might try to add these to your path to solve your problem.

If sample1 and sample 2 aren't separate apps, an even better way would be to make sample1 and sample2 android library and link them to your testingsamples. Thus both sample1 and sample2 R's are fused into testingsamples'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the package name within you src folder and the one defined in the app's Manifest.xml. Normally when you create a new project in Eclipse they are equal, but they don't have to.

All your projects can use the same package structure in their src folders. But to show Android that the both apps sample1 and sample2 are different apps, their package names in the the manifest files have to be different.

**UPDATE**

Sorry I realized this doesn't solve the problem as the R class is generated under the package name defined in den manifest.

Comment: This. Your AndroidManifest.xml defines which "main" to run and needs to specify which classes are a part of the same app.

Comment: @Flo But R gets the paht from manifest so if in manifest I set path to `com.some.path` R will be `com.some.path.R` and this is not solution for me as I need R to be in the same places in both projects.

Comment: If you really fuse them into one application like you stated, are you really sure you are aware of the consequences? imagine what you want to happen when you launch 'adb install myApk1.apk; adb install myApk2.apk' and especially 'adb uninstall my.package.name'.

Every application has only one root package name - if you bind the two apps together they will be only one app.

Comment: @ViToBrothers Sorry, you're right. I mixed this up, the R class is indeed generated under the package name defined in the Manifest.

Comment: Perhaps you should give @Laucia's solution a try an extract the code of both apps into its own library project. So you can test everything in one test app and each "real" app uses its library project.

Comment: You should update your question with the reason why you have to test both apps within one test app. Perhaps someone might have an idea how to do it differently without the described side effects.